# How to extract the common words before particular symbol and find particular word

Tags: python, cpu-word

IF I have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 0,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 1,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 2,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 3,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 4,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 5,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 6,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 7,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 8,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP3_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 9,
          "p18_84pp_2B_MVP1_GoodiesT2-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 10}
```

1. I want to extract the common part `g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0` before the first `-`.
2. also I want add a `_MIX` to follow `g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0` when finding the particular word `MIX` in first group . Assume that I am able to classify two groups depending on whether is `MIX` or `FIX` in myDict, then the final Output dictionary:

```
OutputNameDict= {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0_MIX" : 0,
                  "h18_84pp_3A_MVP_GoodiesT1_FIX" : 1,
                  "p18_84pp_2B_MVP_FIX": 2}
```

Is there any function I could use to find common part? How pick up the word before or after particular symbol like `-` and find particular words like `MIX` or `FIX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` to get the common part:

```
s = "g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt"
n = s.split('-')[0]
```

In fact, `split` will give you a list of each token delimited by `'-'`, so `s.split('-')` yields:

```
['g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0', 'HKJ', 'DFG_MIX', 'CMVP1_Y1000', 'MIX.txt']
```

To see if `MIX` or `FIX` is in a string, you can use `in`:

```
if 'MIX' in s:
    print "then MIX is in the string s"
```

If you want to get rid if the numbers after `'MVP'`, you can use `re` module:

```
import re
s = 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0'
s = re.sub('MVP[0-9]*','MVP',s)
```

Here is a sample function to get a list of the common parts:

```
def foo(mydict):
    return [re.sub('MVP[0-9]*', 'MVP', k.split('-')[0]) for k in mydict]
```

Comment: @jh314Thank you. Very helpful. The only thing here is I want `g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0` without numbers like `1` following `MVP`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @jH314One more question, if I consider variable `X=s.split('_')[3] #MVP1`, seem that I am not able to use `re.sub`.

Comment: Are you using `re.sub('MVP[0-9]*','MVP',X)` ?

Comment: No, I mean if I don't know `s.split('_')[3]` is `MVP1`, in my other study cases, it can be any other word, but I know it's on position `[3]`. For this case, I know my variable `X = MVP1`, if I want more generic. So is there way to get `MVP` by not typing `MVP` inside the `re.sub('MVP[0-9]*','MVP',X)`

Comment: What `re.sub` does is finds a pattern, and replaces that pattern with someting else.  So `re.sub('MVP[0-9]*','MVP',X)` replaces any string of the form 'MVP' followed by any number of digits with 'MVP' only (essentially removes any digits directly after 'MVP').

Comment: I see. Do you think is there any function to archive my goal?

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin function.  But you can certainly write your own.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Could provide a clue for me to start writing the code?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: I looked at python documentation `re` module, got answer by using `RightLetter = re.split('[0-9]+',s.split('_')[3])[0]   # RightLetter =MVP`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index()` function to find your dashes, then with that knowledge you can take the rest of the string past that point. For instance,

```
mydict = {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 0,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 1,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 2,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 3,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 4,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 5,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 6,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 7,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 8,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 9}

for value in sorted(mydict.iterkeys()):
        index = value.index('-')
        extracted = value[index+1:-4] # Goes past the first occurrence of - and removes .txt from the end
        print extracted[-3:] # Find the last 3 letters in the string
```

Will print the following:

```
MIX
MIX
MIX
MIX
MIX
MIX
MIX
FIX
FIX
FIX
```

Then if statements can be used to do what you would like.

If you want to extract just the common part.

```
index = value.index('-')
extracted = value[:index] # Will get g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0
```

Then to figure out the ending to use. If you know the ending of the mydict value will always be MIX.txt or FIX.txt then you can do this.

```
for value in sorted(mydict.iterkeys()):
    ending = value[-7:-4]
    index = value.index('-')
    extracted = value[:index]
    print "%s_%s" % (extracted, ending)
```

Which prints

```
g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0_MIX
g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0_MIX
h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1_FIX
h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1_FIX
h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1_FIX
```

Then you add it to the extracted dictionary.

Comment: @nwalshThank you. About point 1 the common part? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @nwalshIt's always ending with MIX.txt and FIX.txt, thank you. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. My complete code as following. Any suggestion to optimize it?

```
import re

mydict = {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 0,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 1,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 2,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 3,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 4,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 5,    
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 6,    
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 7,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 8,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP3_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 9,
          "p18_84pp_2B_MVP1_GoodiesT2-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 10}

ExtractDict = {}
start = 0
for stringList in sorted(mydict.iterkeys()):
    stringList = stringList.split('.')[0]  
    underscore = stringList.split('_')   
    Area= re.split('[0-9]+',stringList.split('_')[3])[0] # MVP and etc.       
    CaseNameString=underscore[0]+"_"+underscore[1]+"_"+underscore[2]+"_"+Area #g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0 and etc.
    postfix= stringList.split('-')[4]
    Newstring= CaseNameString + "_" + postfix   
    ExtractDict[Newstring]= start
    start += 1
startagain =0
OutputNameDict = {}
for OutputNameList in sorted(ExtractDict.iterkeys()):
    OutputNameDict[OutputNameList] = startagain
    startagain +=1

#OutputNameDict = {'h18_84pp_3A_MVP_FIX': 1, 'p18_84pp_2B_MVP_FIX': 2, 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP_MIX': 0}
```