# how to group new dictionaries by using common strings from my dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, grouping

Refer to my previous question: [How to extract the common words before particular symbol and find particular word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701804)

```
mydict = {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 0,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 1,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 2,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 3,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 4,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 5,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 6,
          "g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 7,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 8,
          "h18_84pp_3A_MVP3_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 9,
          "p18_84pp_2B_MVP1_GoodiesT2-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 10}
```

and I already got my OutputNameDict,

```
OutputNameDict = {'h18_84pp_3A_MVP_FIX': 1, 'p18_84pp_2B_MVP_FIX': 2, 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP_MIX': 0}
```

**Now what I want to do is to group three new dictionaries by using my common strings `CaseNameString`(refer to previous question) and values from OutputNameDict.**

The idea result will like:

Group1. mydict0 using value `0` in `OutputNameDict` and string `g18_84pp_2A_MVP_GoodiesT0` in`CaseNameString`.

> ```
> mydict0 = {"g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 0,               
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 1,
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 2,
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 3,
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 4,
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 5,
>            "g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt" : 6}
> ```

Group2. mydict1 using value `1` in `OutputNameDict` and string `h18_84pp_3A_MVP_GoodiesT1` in`CaseNameString`.

> ```
> mydict1 ={"h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 0,
>           "h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 1,
>           "h18_84pp_3A_MVP3_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 2}
> ```

Group3. mydict2 using value `2` in `OutputNameDict` and string `p18_84pp_2B_MVP_GoodiesT2`  in`CaseNameString`.

> ```
> mydict2 ={"p18_84pp_2B_MVP1_GoodiesT2-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt" : 0}
> ```

Any suggestion? Is there any function to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change your `OutputNameDict` keys to be regular expression patterns, as follows:

```
OutputNameDict = {'h18_84pp_3A_MVP.*FIX': 1, 'p18_84pp_2B_MVP.*FIX': 2, 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP.*MIX': 0}
```

Then, using the `re` regular expression module, use that to match against the keys in `mydict`, and place the dictionary element into the appropriate key in `output_dicts` dictionary, as follows

```
import collections
import re
output_dicts = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    for pattern, suffix in OutputNameDict.iteritems():
        if re.match(pattern,k):
            output_dicts['mydict' + str(suffix)][k] = v
            break
    else:
        output_dicts['not matched'][k] = v
```

This results in the `output_dicts` dictionary populated as follows

```
for k, v in output_dicts.iteritems():
    print k
    print v
    print
```

Which outputs

```
mydict1
{'h18_84pp_3A_MVP2_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP2_Y1000-FIX.txt': 8, 
 'h18_84pp_3A_MVP3_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt': 9, 
 'h18_84pp_3A_MVP1_GoodiesT1-HKJ-DFG-CMVP1_Y1000-FIX.txt': 6}

mydict0
{'g18_84pp_2A_MVP1_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP1_Y1000-MIX.txt': 0,
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP2_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP2_Y1000-MIX.txt': 1, 
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP4_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP4_Y1000-MIX.txt': 3, 
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP5_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP5_Y1000-MIX.txt': 4, 
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP3_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP3_Y1000-MIX.txt': 2, 
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP6_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP6_Y1000-MIX.txt': 5, 
 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP7_GoodiesT0-HKJ-DFG_MIX-CMVP7_Y1000-MIX.txt': 7}

mydict2
{'p18_84pp_2B_MVP1_GoodiesT2-HKJ-DFG-CMVP3_Y1000-FIX.txt': 10}
```

Comment: @mtaddIf I to match til `GoodiesT0`,`GoodiesT1` and `GoodiesT2`, the expression `OutputNameDict ={'h18_84pp_3A_MVP.*_GoodiesT1.*FIX': 1, 'p18_84pp_2B_MVP.*_GoodiesT2.*FIX': 2, 'g18_84pp_2A_MVP.*_GoodiesT0.*MIX': 0}` works well for me.

Comment: regular expressions are very flexible, and can capture as specifically, or as greedily as you wish to specify.  For debugging, I'd also consider adding an else clause to the inner for loop to place any entries in `mydict` that don't match one of your regular expressions into a 'not matched' dictionary entry in `output_dicts`, which I'll add to the answer as an example.

Comment: One more question. How about if I want `mydict0`, `mydict1` and `mydict2` have values start at `0` then following `1`, `2`, `3`...

Comment: dictionaries store data unordered for performance reasons.  If you want to display the items in order, you can use the `sorted` method, e.g. `sorted(mydict.iteritems(),key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Thanks. It's useful for me.